# How do I get the actual width of a dynamically created label?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window with a list of tasks, and I want to move a spinner to be immediately right of the task name when it is processing.

However, I'm unable to get the "true" width of the labels - it always returns the same value (503) for each label, regardless of content.

I am trying to move the spinner on Content Rendered as follows:

```
private async void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] labels = { "I am sailing", "I am going for a walk", "I am learning to juggle", "I have gone fishing", "I am doing something else" };
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
    {
        string name = labels[i].Replace(" ", "");
        Label lbl = MyGrid.Children.OfType<Label>()
            .First(j => j.Name == name);

        await Task.Run(() => DummyTask());
        var position = lbl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        Spinner.Margin = new Thickness(lbl.ActualWidth + 30, position.Y, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

However, because the value always returns at 503, the spinner is moved off the window's visible area.

How do I get the "real" width of the label (i.e. of the content).

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? It seems to me that this could be done by just using something like `StackPanel` and just put the control next to the label that way.

Comment: Better put the Label (or a TextBlock) and the Spinner in a horizontal StackPanel and let WPF layout do the job.

Comment: Cheers guys - much better idea!